# Stripe Product PHP Integration

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i am in the process of integrating stripe with my PHP Application and i can get one product working but i am wanting to add multiple products.

I am using the StripeHelper.php file but when i add a second case it keeps processing to purchase the 1st product

here is my code.

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
include_once "constants.php";
class StripeHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Stripe\StripeClient
     */
    public $stripeClient;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stripeClient = new \Stripe\StripeClient(STRIPE_API_SECRET_KEY);
    }
    /**
     * Create product
     * @return \Stripe\Product
     * @throws \Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException
     */
    public function createProducts()
    {
        return $this->stripeClient->products->create(array(
            'name' => 'Product 1',
            'description' => 'Product 1.',
    ));
    return $this->stripeClient->products->create(array(
            'name' => 'Product 2',
            'description' => 'Product 2.',
    ));
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Create price
     * @param $product
     * @param $productPrice
     * @return \Stripe\Price
     * @throws \Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException
     */
    public function createProductPrice($product, $productPrice)
    {
        return $this->stripeClient->prices->create(array(
            'unit_amount' => $productPrice * 1,
            'currency' => 'GBP',
            'product' => $product->id,
        ));
        return $this->stripeClient->prices->create(array(
            'unit_amount' => $productPrice * 2,
            'currency' => 'GBP',
            'product' => $product->id,
        ));
    }
    
    /**
     * Get session detail
     * @param $sessionId
     * @return \Stripe\Checkout\Session
     * @throws \Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException
     */
    public function getSession($sessionId)
    {
        return $this->stripeClient->checkout->sessions->retrieve($sessionId);
    }
}
```

i have tried adding extra lines and products emulating existing code

i am expecting to be able to list multiple products on my index page and proceed to checkout the different product.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [return](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) keyword will immediately stop execution of that function. For example, with

```php
function foo() {
    return doA();
    return doB();
}
```

only `doA()` will be called.